# Android Preloaded apps - Does Google Play take them into account to compute total number of installs?

Tags: google-play-store

I would like to know whether or not **preloaded apps are taken into account by Google Play to compute the total number of installs** of an app.

I read many articles, among which [this one](https://www.androidcentral.com/ask-ac-how-many-installs-does-app-really-have), but I did not find yet a clear answer to this question.

Can someone provide an answer to this question? Hopefully a link to some official Google Play / Android Developer Documentation page.. ;-)

Thanks.

PS:
I sent a question to Google using contact form on Google Play Console, but did not receive an answer yet.
And, of course, I also read many documentation pages on Google Play Console portal.

Comment: @beeshyams I am sorry, but do not follow. Can you explain more and hopefully give me some links / urls? I am searching for certainty about that. Thanks

Comment: Sorry can't share anything concrete that can help. What I was saying was that it won't count as install as a best guess

Comment: I cannot say for sure, but I'd say the download/install counter is triggered only when accessed via Playstore. Preinstalled apps get on devices a different way (to my knowledge, OEMs get one package and install that on as many devices as needed), so Playstore most likely couldn't even know the numbers. As said, my *assumptions* – I cannot tell for sure.

Comment: @Izzy thanks for the info. But what if a user go to the Play store app and update the preloaded app? Will it then be taken into account?

Comment: That I cannot tell. The question then must read: "Do updates count as Installs for an app's 'number of installs'?" Logic would say: No. Because even if I installed an app from there, I should still be just "one user" of that app, regardless of how many versions I tried.

Comment: @Izzy No, the question about "updates" you mentioned is not what I mean. I think my initial question is clear enough. Anyway, thanks for your time trying to help ;-)

Comment: Then the fact that preloaded apps are not installed from/via Playstore should answer your question?

Comment: I'd suggest programming this into the application, If you truly want to total number of installations then have your app access a website when opening, the website can count the different devices that have accessed it and Viola